# Can you provide relevant study aids for Discrete Mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I am taking a discrete mathematics course this spring for my major in cyber security and trying to find study aids( amazon ), online groups, or other sites.

The assigned book is
$$"Discrete\ Mathematics\ and\ Its\ Applications\ 7th\ ed."$$
$$\mbox{isbn-}13 : 978\mbox{-}0073383095$$

Comment: You can try Cryptology books there are many books available

Comment: a good way of referring to a book is to include the *author* as well.